# Can I Customize Category Codes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm playing around with some categorical data, called 'Ratings'.  My data looks like this (in a dataframe):

```
AAA
AA
A
A+
BBB
BB
B
B+
```

I have about 25 categories.  Now, I'm trying to get a corresponding field that is related to this Ratings field.  I'd like to see this:

```
30
29
28
27
26
25
24
23
```

...
down to 1, at the end.  So far, I have tested this small piece of code.

```
modDF['Rating'] = modDF['Rating'].astype('category')
modDF['RatingCode'] = modDF['Rating'].cat.codes
```

That gives me categories, but not according to the logic I want to use.  It almost looks like it's working but in the reverse order, but the ratings with the '+' character look weird.  Is there some way to assign category codes based on some kind of vlookup, or something similar to that?  Thanks.

Comment: This may have to be done manually.  I don't see any way a computer is going to learn that AAA is better than BBB and this is better than CCC.  I'm sure the computer can easily map a value of 30 to AAA, 20 to BBB, and 10 to CCC, and then say 20 is better than 10 and 30 is better than 20.  I think a manual mapping exercise is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the ratings will follow a certain pattern (i.e. XXX, XX, XX, X+), you could do something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import string

# df with dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(['AAA', 'AA', 'A', 'A+', 'BBB', 'BB', 'B', 'B+'], columns=['Ratings'])

# collect ratings and assign a decreasing value to them
ratings = [[letter*3, letter*2, letter, letter+'+'] for letter in string.ascii_uppercase]  # create all possible ratings in order
ratings = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ratings))  # flatten list
ratings_code = dict(zip(ratings, reversed(range(len(ratings)))))

# map rating code to original rating
df['RatingCode'] = df.Ratings.map(ratings_code)
```

Depending on your expectations of the range of `RatingCode`, you'll need to adjust `reversed(range(len(ratings)))` or limit the letters used in the list comprehension.

Comment: Wow!  That's very, very cool.  I didn't know you could do that.  I guess there are not many limitations in the Python world.  Thanks for the enlightenment.